# Keyboard mapping overrides

Tags: gnome, keyboard, wayland, 21.10

I just upgraded to 21.10, and since firefox wouldn't no longer find a display and start on X, I'm moving to Wayland (and happy about it).

However, I'm having problems on doing keyboard mapping override. I'd like to customize a bit my Engilsh Dvorak keyboard layout. I'm successfully using following config on Fedora, but unable to get it loading or working on Ubuntu.

```
xkb_keymap {
xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
xkb_types     { include "default"   };
xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
xkb_symbols   {
    include "pc+us(dvorak)+inet(evdev)+ctrl(nocaps)+eurosign(e)+kpdl(dot)"
    // Less than/Greater than/Pipe key on Swedish keyboards becomes Compose
    replace key <LSGT> { [ adiaeresis, odiaeresis ] };
    // Scroll Lock becomes Compose
    // replace key <SCLK> { [ Multi_key ] };
};
xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
```

};